# JOIN query not working in iphone device but working in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have 2 tables **Resources**,**ResourceViewHistory**
Resources has these fields:**ResourceId**,**TypeId**,**Name**,**Url**,**IsFavorite**,**LanguageCode**,**CategoryId**.
ResourceViewHistory has these fields:**ViewId**,**ResourceId**,**DateViewed**,**Longitude**,**Latitude**

I want result set for ResourceId in Resources table: Name,Url,IsFavorite,ResourceId and DateViewed,Longitude,Latitude for same ResourceId in ResourceViewHistory table and CategoryId=1,TypeId=1

My query is:

```
SELECT r.ResourceId,Url,Name,IsFavorite,max(v.DateViewed) AS LastVisited,Longitude,Latitude 
FROM Resources r 
LEFT JOIN ResourceViewHistory v  on (r.ResourceId=v.ResourceId) 
WHERE CategoryId=1 AND TypeId=1 
GROUP BY r.ResourceId
```

the above query is working in simulator but not working in iPhone device.My objectiveC code is below.The arrUrlDetails array is always showing 0 objects

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getUrlDetails{
NSString *strHome = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/test.sqlite",strHome];

NSMutableArray *arrUrlDetails=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *db;
int n = sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String], &db);
if (n==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *strQuery=@"SELECT r.ResourceId,Url,Name,IsFavorite,max(v.DateViewed) AS LastVisited,Longitude,Latitude FROM Resources r LEFT JOIN ResourceViewHistory v  on (r.ResourceId=v.ResourceId) where CategoryId=1 AND TypeId=1 group by r.ResourceId";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    const char *err_msg;

    int res=sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &stmt, &err_msg);
    if (res == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {


            Resources *resources=[[Resources alloc]init];
            resources.resourceId=sqlite3_column_int(stmt,0);
            resources.name=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
            resources.url=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            resources.isFavorite=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];
            resources.dateViewed=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)];
            resources.latitude=sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 6);

            [arrUrlDetails addObject:resources];

        }
    }

}

return arrUrlDetails;
```

}

Comment: Is the database even opening? I guess that would be the first thing I would check. Can you add an `NSLog()` to verify that your outermost `if` statement is executing?

Comment: ya its executing.The second if stmt(i.e:if(res==SQLITE_OK) is not executing

Comment: Does the `err_msg` reveal anything?

Comment: err_msg is showing ""

Comment: The int variable 'res' should be =0 but its =1 as SQLITE_OK==0

Comment: 1 is `SQLITE_ERROR`. There should be something in `err_msg`. You are remembering that `err_msg` is a pointer, correct?

Comment: err_msg is "" only.Now how to solve if SQLITE_OK==1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50610/discussion-between-user2105505-and-user2552751)